# How to put datagrid into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, datagrid

I have a `datagrid` and I want to put the specific column into an array, how I suppose to do it? My xaml looks like:

```
<Datagrid x:Name="dgSample" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsView}"
   <Datagrid.Columns>
      <DatagridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding ProductName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      <DatagridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding ProductValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      ...
```

And the Array is defined by:

```
public static ushort[] temp = new ushort[20];
```

How to put **Column** `Value` in the **Datagrid** `dgSample` into **Array** `temp`? Thanks in advance!

-------------------------------------update-------------------------------------

```
    private ICollectionView _ProductsView;
    public ICollectionView ProductsView
    {
        get { return _ProductsView; }
        set
        {
            _ProductsView = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateProducts()
    {
        _ds = sdb.GetProducts();
        ProductsView = new ListCollectionView(_ds.Tables["Products"].DefaultView)
        {
            Filter = obj =>
            {
                var Product= obj as DataRowView;
                return SelectedProduct != null && SelectedProduct.ModelName == Product["ProductName"].ToString();
            }
        };
    }


    public DataSet GetProducts()
    {
        DataSet ds = StoreDbDataSet.ReadDataSet();

        ObservableCollection<Product> products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        foreach (DataRow productRow in ds.Tables["Products"].Rows)
        {
            products.Add(new Product((string)productRow["ProductName"],
                (UInt16)productRow["ProductValue"]));
        }
        return StoreDbDataSet.ReadDataSet();
    }

namespace ProductDatabase
{
    public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ...
     }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _put column ... into Array temp_? `DataGridColumn` is not `ushort` which is the type of your array.

Comment: You could try something like `var values = myDataGrid.Columns.Where(c => c.Header.ToString() == "Name").Select(c => Convert.ToUInt16(c.GetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty))).ToArray();`. It is untested though, this gets the column using header name, replace "Name" with "Value" if that is the required column. Assuming all the values in the column can be converted to `ushort`, but I'd suggest checking for null or non-convertable values.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL You are absolutely wrong with your solution. You are trying to get `TextBlock.Text` property of a `DataGridColumn`. If column _Name_ is the only column with this name in `DataGrid` you'll get single value. And this value is not a value of some row in table.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Your suggestion runs with error: `The name 'value' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Yes, as @Maxim mentioned, my suggestion is completely wrong. Since I am working with datagrids at the moment, I can have a real answer for you soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're doing this in code-behind and not in the ViewModel, you could use this piece of code to get the array:

*Assuming the data type of each item in the datagrid is "Product"*

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgSample.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var row = dgSample.Items[i] as Product;
    if (row != null)
        temp[i] = Convert.ToUInt16(row.ProductValue);    //or if it is a ushort already, no need to Convert
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using the MVVM structure and have a ViewModel, since your items source code is `ItemsSource="{Binding Product, Mode=TwoWay}"` (*did you mean Products?*):

**EDIT:**

Since you're using an ICollectionView, you can use a foreach to directly loop over the elements, or simply `Cast` it to your data type and convert to a list or array, as follows

```
temp = ProductsView.Cast<Product>().Select(p => Convert.ToUInt16(p.ProductValue)).ToArray();
```

If your variable is called ProductID, or anything else, replace `ProductValue` by that name.

As suggested by Maxim, your itemssource binding does not need to by TwoWay, rather it would make sense for your rows to have that (if you are allowing users to edit them):

```
<Datagrid x:Name="dgSample" ItemsSource="{Binding Product}"
    <Datagrid.Columns>
        <DatagridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding ProductName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <DatagridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding ProductValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
         ...
```

Comment: Second code snippet is the solution that should be used. Also note for @barry: read about binding properties before use them. `Mode=TwoWay` doesn't make sense for `ItemsSource`. It is sad that almost every day I see new questions with this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my `ProductsView` is declared as `ICollectionView` which does not contain the method `Select`.

Comment: @barry Hi, so could you let me know what ObservableCollection/List is the source for that ICollectionView? Or you could update your question to add the declaration of ProductsView as well as the List bound to it.

Comment: @barry `ICollectionView` is `IEnumerable` so you can use `OfType<Product>` on it or on `SourceCollection` of collection view. Please learn C# and use MSDN to inspect types.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I'm new to C# and sorry for keeping on asking you, but It seems `unable to cast object type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'ProductDatabase.Module'`

Comment: May I see the line of code that you used, the one that gives this error?

Comment: It's exactly the same as you posted `return ProductsView.Cast<Product>().Select(p =>Convert.ToUInt16(p.ParamValue)).ToArray();` The ProductsView is defined in the **ViewModel** as ICollectionView , the Product is define in another project  in the namespace **ProductDatabase**  both are shown in the update above.

Comment: If you're returning that, you need to change the method return type to match, e.g. public Product[] *myMethod* ()`

Comment: But this `ProductsView.Cast<Product>().Select(p =>Convert.ToUInt16(p.ParamValue)).ToArray()` returns to the type ushort[]

Comment: @barry Actually you're right, though I don't think that's even the problem. Try changing your line `var Product= obj as DataRowView;` to `var Prod = obj as Product;` and `return SelectedProduct != null && SelectedProduct.ModelName == Product["ProductName"].ToString();` to `return SelectedProduct != null && SelectedProduct.ModelName == Prod["ProductName"].ToString();`. Also, where did `ProductDatabase.Module` come from? I saw that class in a separate question by someone named Lee Barry ;)

Comment: You catch me out, this really beats me, I would appreciate if you could take a look at the full project.[link](https://github.com/Baaaaaarry/PX1_Configurator)

Comment: @barry Which files/lines are you having a problem with? There are so many, I don't know where to look.

Comment: /PX1_Configurator/ViewModel/MainViewModel.cs

Comment: I see some issues, basically you never set `readRegisters` value, maybe you can just do this inside `DatagridToArray()` and return void? Also, the difference between [Line 122](https://github.com/Baaaaaarry/PX1_Configurator/blob/master/PX1_Configurator/ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs#L122) and [Line 123](https://github.com/Baaaaaarry/PX1_Configurator/blob/master/PX1_Configurator/ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs#L123) is that `ModulesView.Cast` will take the *filtered* values, while `_ds.Tables["Modules"].` gives all the modules. Anyways, here is my email: keyurpatel30@hotmail.com. Email me.